# Foward declaring boost::signals2::signal<void()>

Tags: c++, templates, boost

I'm trying to forward declare boost signal, so I don't need to include header file when the signal is not used.

I thought this would work:

```
namespace boost
{
namespace signals2
{
  class signal<void()>;
}
}
```

But get the error "signal is not a template"

Is there a way to do this?

Edit:
More information: An example of what I'm trying to do, mainly keep the 
#include  out of the majority of my code base.

```
#include <memory>

/// Forward declaration here:

/// .H File
class ExampleClass
{
public:
  boost::signals2::signal<void()> & GetSignal();

protected:
  std::shared_ptr<boost::signals2::signal<void()>> _signal_pointer;
};
```

.CPP

```
#include "boost/signals2.hpp"
boost::signals2::signal<void()> & ExampleClass::GetSignal()
{
  if (!_signal_pointer)
  {
    _signal_pointer.reset(new boost::signals2::signal<void()>());
  }

  return *_signal_pointer;
}
```

Comment: Seems like a bit of a tricky one. The reason I want so, is I would like a class that when asked via the header to give a signal, as a reference, it can do. Otherwise, I don't want to use the thousands of lines of code to slow down my compile times on many other classes that do use it.

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this concrete compiler error if you add `template<>`

```
namespace boost
{
namespace signals2
{
  template<typename T>
  struct signal;

  template<>
  class signal<void()>;
}
}
```

Because of before you can declare specialization of `template`,
you should declare `template` by it self. And then actually you
can write just:

```
namespace boost
{
namespace signals2
{
  template<typename T>
  struct signal;
}
}
```

Because of you use only forward declaration, not implement `template`,
so there is no point to specialize it.

But it is not really help you.
Yes compiler error is gone in case if you nowhere use `boost::signals2`,
but if you use such include file, somewhere where with "real" `boost::singals2`
is included you get error about redeclaration of `signal`, this is because
of real `boost::signals2::signal` take 5-7 template arguments, don't remember exactly, and have some defaults for the most of them.

Comment: There's stuff like locking policies and things like that.

Answer (score -1):

Signals2 is not designed to be "pimpl"ed. It's designed to be *in your public interface*.

If you don't want that, wrap it in your own pimpl-wrappers. But you should ask yourself "why" first.

Comment: The obvious answer to "why" is: because including `signals2\signal.hpp` is very expensive - it can easily take > 1s on a reasonably fast machine. Multiply that by a large number of files that are including your header file, and you have a very good reason for wanting to avoid it.